# iOS Core Data error - Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm tearing my hair out with this issue, which seems like it should be something really simple.  iOS / Objective C is new to me, so maybe I'm just not grasping something fundamental.

The problem is that I've added a new entity to my Core Data model, and set up a one-to-many relationship.  The model already had two entities that had a one-to-one relationship.

[image: Core Data Model]

The Players entity is the new one.

I have a UITableViewController where I'm saving to the attributes from UITextFields. This worked fine for the original configuration of Teams/TeamDetails, but it crashes out with the following error when I add in the Players entity to the code:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason:   'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: 
property = "playerDetails"; desired type = NSSet; given type = Players;
```

So, in my Save method, I had:

```
Teams *team = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Teams" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
TeamDetails *teamdetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TeamDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

team.teamDetails = teamdetails;
```

then I go on to set the attributes like:

```
team.teamName = teamNameTextField.text;
team.teamDetails.managerName = managerNameTextField.text;
```

Which all worked no problem.  Now I extend this to incorporate the Players Entity:

```
Players *playerDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Players" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

team.playerDetails = playerDetails;
```

And I get the error above.  I've tried the following:

```
[team setPlayerDetails:playerDetails];
```

But this doesn't make any difference.  I also tried:

```
NSSet *playerDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Players" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

But again, no difference - it still thinks it's getting an object of type Players rather than NSSet.

I feel like I'm just not grasping something simple, so any help would ge very much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`playerDetails` is a to-many relationship, so the value of `team.playerDetails` is a *set* of players, not a single player object. You can either use

```
[team addPlayerDetailsObject:playerDetails];
```

or more simply, using the inverse relationship:

```
playerDetails.team = team;
```

Comment: Fantastic, that works a treat.  I had a feeling it would be something so simple, I just couldn't put my finger on it.  Thanks very much :)