# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "detail";

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Here is my data model:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[failedBankInfo setValue:@"Test Bank" forKeyPath:@"name"];
[failedBankInfo setValue:@"Testville" forKeyPath:@"city"];
[failedBankInfo setValue:@"Testland" forKeyPath:@"state"];

NSManagedObject *failedBankDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FailedBankDetail" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[failedBankDetails setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"closeDate"];
[failedBankDetails setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"updateDate"];
[failedBankDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12345] forKey:@"zip"];
[failedBankDetails setValue:failedBankInfo forKeyPath:@"info"];
[failedBankInfo setValue:failedBankDetails forKey:@"detail"];

NSError *error;
if(![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"name"]);
    NSManagedObject *details = [info valueForKey:@"details"];
    NSLog(@"Zip: %@", [details valueForKey:@"zip"]);
}
```

Here is a trace log:

```
2014-07-14 14:56:57.080 FailedBankCD[87194:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "detail"; desired type = NSSet; given type = NSManagedObject; value = <NSManagedObject: 0x8c452d0> (entity: FailedBankDetail; id: 0x8c63740 <x-coredata:///FailedBankDetail/t5A5AD25D-C89A-4FA2-A776-C91A3F0413083> ; data: {
    closeDate = "2014-07-14 10:56:55 +0000";
    info = "0x8c60b40 <x-coredata:///FailedBankInfo/t5A5AD25D-C89A-4FA2-A776-C91A3F0413082>";
    updateDate = "2014-07-14 10:56:55 +0000";
    zip = 12345;
}).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
[failedBankInfo setValue:failedBankDetails forKey:@"detail"];
```

What is the reason of the problem and how can I fix it ?

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082133/ios-core-data-error-unacceptable-type-of-value-for-to-many-relationship

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that I can change my relation from 'to-many' to 'to-one' and my code will works. But my knowledge is not enough to modify my code to use it with 'to-many' relationship.  So I will be thankful for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, then I will make this clearer:

Instead of

```
[failedBankInfo setValue:failedBankDetails forKey:@"detail"];
```

use

```
[failedBankInfo addDetail:failedBankDetails];
```

and let the magic happen.
The point is, that you do have one-to-many which is represented by a set. So instead of overwriting the set with a single managed object you add it.

Comment: Hmm... I can not find addDetail method for NSManagedObject (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html).  And my Xcode confirm it.

Comment: That is no Method implemented by NSManagedObject. In your Source you should have a FailedBankInfo.h that extents NSManagedObject. Your Core Data Scheme states, that this class has a detail property, that stores connected FailedBankDetail objects. addDetail is conveniently autogenerated to adress this Scheme connection.

Comment: If you do not have the FailedBankInfo.h you can autogenerate it by xcode by going to your Core Data Scheme, marking the FailedBankInfo class there then select File->New->File from the Xcode menu and select "NSManagedObject subclass" from the Core Data group.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the header files for your NSManagedObject(s). Your FailedBankInfo class has a to-many relationship with FailedBankDetail. This means 1 FailedBankInfo can have many FailedBankDetail object references and implies that the detail relationship is an NSSet. The inverse is a to-one relationship so it is a simple FailedBankDetail object. Your problem is with this line:

```
[failedBankInfo setValue:failedBankDetails forKey:@"detail"];
```

You need to assign an NSSet (of FailedBankDetail objects even if it is a set of 1 object). There are convenience methods defined in the header of FailedBankInfo that make this easy to do.