# How to get relation values from table in coredatabase

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My fetch request is fetching relational value with 0 itms in NSSet. But I can see the values in database.

**Printing description of currency:
▿ Optional
  - some : 0 elements**

I am trying to get the values like below
data.value(forKey: "country_currency") as? [Currencies]

or

let currency = countryObj.country_currency

Fetch request is:

let request:NSFetchRequest = EntityCountry.fetchRequest()

[image]
[image]

Comment: `EntityCurrencies` is not equal to `Currencies`. Name entities always in singular form and without redundant prefixes -> `Currency`, `Country` and `Language`

Comment: updated the entity name and relation name... but still I am not getting record from Currency table.

▿ Optional<NSSet>
  - some : 0 elements
Printing description of currency:
0 elements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082133/ios-core-data-error-unacceptable-type-of-value-for-to-many-relationship

Good explanation.